# Usar Update con INNER JOIN en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Que tal,

Estoy ejecutando una senencia en Oracle (**Update**) utilizando **INNER JOIN**, pero no he podido hacerlo. Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.status = '2', target_date=SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM Table_A  A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
   ON A.employee_number=B.employee_number and A.course_number=B.course_number
 WHERE A.status = '1' and NVL(B.employee_number,'')=''
```

El error que me aparece al momento de ejecutar la sentencia es el siguiente :

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

La verdad no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal. ¿Alguna sugerencia a mi problema?

Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no he podido hacerlo"? ¿Te da algún error? ¿No te actualiza los registros que intentas actualizar? ¿Qué es lo que quieres que haga la sentencia y que hace en realidad?

Comment: Buen dia Asier, lo que intento decir es que al momento de ejecutar la sentencia (Update), me aparece un error. Lo unico que necesito es que de acuerdo a la condición del Query alctualice los registro de la tabla A haciendo un INNER JOIN con la tabla B. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esa sintaxis de UPDATE con JOIN es más propia de SQL Server. En Oracle no está soportada.

No he podido probarlo pero debería ser algo así:

```
UPDATE
(SELECT A.status, A.target_date
    FROM Table_A  A 
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
        ON A.employee_number=B.employee_number
            AND A.course_number=B.course_number
    WHERE A.status = '1' 
        AND NVL(B.employee_number,'')='') t
SET t.status = '2', t.target_date = SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

Otra opción:

```
UPDATE Table_A SET Table_A.status = '2', Table_A.target_date = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE Table_A.status = '1'
    AND COALESCE(Table_A.employee_number, '')=''
    AND EXISTS (SELECT Table_B.course_number
                FROM Table_B
                WHERE Table_B.course_number = Table_A.course_number
                    AND Table_B.employee_number = Table_A.employee_number);
```

Comment: Que tal Asier, sigo con el problema, me sigue marcando error. :(. Pero muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿El mismo error?

Comment: El error que me aparece es:
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"   Pero si hago un simple Update lo hace sin ningun problema, asi que no creo que sea por un problema de privilegios.

Comment: También podrías hacerlo con una subquery, edito para ponerte el ejemplo

Comment: Ahora el error que me marca es el siguiente: SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

Comment: Cierto, perdona, ya está corregido

Comment: Ahora tengo este otro: SQL Error: ORA-12704: character set mismatch
12704. 00000 -  "character set mismatch"  :(

Comment: Si el tipo de datos de employee_number es NVARCHAR la condición debería ser AND COALESCE(Table_A.employee_number, n'') = n''
 El prefijar con n la cadena indica a Oracle que la cadena es de tipo NVARCHAR.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ahora si funciono muy bien. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

esta parte NVL(B.employee_number,'')='' me resulta curiosa, no se si quizas eso te da problemas y si pruebas con B.employee_number is null

Comment: Buen dia Renata, gracias por tu comentario, Al igual uso esa misma sentencia  "B.employee_number is null"  pero me sigue marcando error.

Comment: Buenas tardes en españa :) .Pregunta tonta, pones el ; final no?

Comment: Que tal Renata, si, si pongo el ; en el código. Gracias por la observación :)