# Update sql con join

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy intentando hacer **`update`** en el que necesitaría hacer un join para juntar dos tablas.

Tengo la tabla `ADJUDICACION` y la tabla `PROVEEDOR`, en el que el join sería: `ADJUDICACION.ID_PROVEEDOR = PROVEEDOR.ID`. Y lo que quería era que `ADJUDICACION.ID_ESTADO = 701` cuando `PROVEEDOR.ID_TIPO_PROVEEDOR = 103`.
Intenté hacer varias cosas parecidas a esta pero nada:

```
    UPDATE ADJUDICACION SET ADJUDICACION.ID_ESTADO = 701
    FROM ADJUDICACION
    JOIN PROVEEDOR ON ADJUDICACION.ID_PROVEEDOR = PROVEEDOR.ID
    WHERE PROVEEDOR.PRO_ID_TIPO_PROVEEDOR = 103;
```

Comment: No en todas las  plataformas funciona igual. Dinos si es MySQL, oracle, postgres,... [en esta respuesta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293347/4435962)  tienes un acercamiento. Espero que te ayude

Comment: @TxemaAlment es en MySQL perdona..

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Usar Update con INNER JOIN en Oracle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11002/usar-update-con-inner-join-en-oracle). Ya existe una respuesta sobre cómo hacerlo en `Oracle`,  solamente habría que cambiar los nombres de tablas/columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma que puede ser óptima, fácil de escribir y de mantener sería esta

```
update ADJUDICACION 
   set ID_ESTADO = 701
 where ID_PROVEEDOR in (select p.ID
                          form PROVEEDOR p
                         where p.PRO_ID_TIPO_PROVEEDOR = 103);
```

Answer (score -1):

Para hacer un Update con un join en ORACLE, puedes hacerlo de manera:

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT table1.value as OLD, table2.CODE as NEW
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.value = table2.DESC
 WHERE table1.UPDATETYPE='blah'
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

Pero como en tu codigo no vas a insertar el valor de otra tabla lo podrias hacer:

```
UPDATE ADJUDICACION a
   SET a.ID_ESTADO = 701
 WHERE EXISTS 
       (SELECT NULL
          FROM ADJUDICACION ad
         INNER JOIN PROVEEDOR p ON ad.ID_PROVEEDOR = p.ID
         WHERE ad.ID_PROVEEDOR = a.ID_PROVEEDOR
           AND p.PRO_ID_TIPO_PROVEEDOR = 103)
```

He encontrado esta informacion en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446834/4435962) y en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9411207/4435962)

Comment: He probado lo que me ha dicho, y me sale el siguiente error:   **Error SQL: ORA-00971: falta la palabra clave SET
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"**

Comment: Me suena de que ese error es de Oracle

Comment: si si perdona, no se que me ha pasado, me he confundido estoy con Oracle...

Comment: @RichardSánchezColiao lo he actualizado para Oracle